# SAT grammar question: Why is this "them" incorrect?

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, subcontinental-english, subordinate-clauses

SAT grammar question:

> There are (more than) 300 million English speakers (in) India, most of (them) acquired English (as) a second language. (No error)

The parentheses designate areas where the grammar of the sentence may be incorrect.  You have to select the area which is in error (or select "No error" if there is no error in the sentence).

(Them) is the error in the sentence.

Can someone explain why (them) is incorrect?

Comment: Seems perfectly alright to me. What is the significance of the brackets?

Comment: @WS2 It's part of how the SAT grammar questions work.  They list a number of options, and you have to select the one that is the error (or "No Error" if the isn't an error).

Comment: 'Them' is *an* incorrect choice; there is 'no error'.

Comment: @Mazura It should be *most of whom* — otherwise it is a **comma-splice error** caused by incorrectly attempting to join together two independent clauses with a mere comma and no conjunction.

Comment: @tchrist: Exactly. So I would rather bracket the comma.

Comment: @tchrist That makes sense.  I really wanted that comma to be a semicolon.

Comment: I think this is a poor question. Obviously, changing 'them' to 'whom' gives an acceptable answer, but so does switching to a semicolon. It's illogical to ask someone to guess which error is being made in such a case, and arguably not strictly a matter of grammar. 'Where can a substitution or omission of a bracketed word [or punctuation mark] give an acceptable sentence?' maybe.

Comment: @Edwin Since the parentheses mark the _only_ possible places to be changed, it must be assumed that everything else in the sentence—including punctuation—is 100% correct. _(Them)_ is the only parenthesised thing that is not correct (whether grammatically or otherwise) if the sentence is taken as being otherwise correct, so I do think it's an all right question. The sentence could also be made correct by adding a full stop after _speakers_ and capitalising the following _in_, but that too would require changing a disallowed part of the sentence.

Comment: It is my understanding that SATs are for Primary School children. I think this involves a rather fine point of grammar for a 10 year old!

Comment: The American SAT is intended for High School juniors or seniors, so normally for someone in the 16-18 range, not a 10-year-old.

Comment: And when I read the sentence, my first response was "none of those words are in error, the problem is a missing 'and' or 'but' after the comma!"

Comment: All the above commenters, please visit [ell.se] :) -- But seriously, what @tchrist said.

Comment: Suggesting migration to [ell.se]

Comment: @Janus Questions on English usage, of all things, should be accurately phrased. 'How can a change of a bracketed word ... ?' **not** 'Where is the error ... ?' or 'Where is the grammar incorrect ... ?'.

Comment: @Edwin If we accept the question as one of grammar (albeit grammar influenced by punctuation), then I actually think it is very accurately and precisely phrased. Asking “How can a change of a bracketed word…?” is a different question, an potentially a more misleading one (you might answer “By moving it to the head of the clause” or something similar). The question here only asks the student to identify _which_ of the bracketed areas contains a grammatical incorrectness—not fix it. (Assuming the two lines after the quote are actually from the question, not just a description by the asker.)

Comment: But it's the whole statement, not one particular word, that constitutes an error.

Answer (score 9):

It should be *most of whom*, not *most of *them*.

Otherwise it is a **comma-splice error** caused by incorrectly attempting to join together two independent clauses with a mere comma and no conjunction.

These are all correctly formed:

1. There are more than 300 million English speakers in India. Most of them acquired English as a second language.
2. There are more than 300 million English speakers in India; most of them acquired English as a second language.
3. There are more than 300 million English speakers in India,  but most of them acquired English as a second language.
4. There are more than 300 million English speakers in India, most of whom acquired English as a second language.

**Without** a semicolon, it cannot be *them*; **with** a semicolon, it cannot be *whom*.

Comment: So you can use 'them' if there was a semi colon? Without so many parentheses I may have caught that; I read it as two clauses automatically. I don't expect people to use colons correctly (and it wasn't one of the options) and I'm not even sure if I just did...

Comment: @Mazura There are no colons in the original, nor should there be. **Without** a semicolon, it cannot be *them*; **with** a semicolon, it cannot be *whom*. And yes, I actually do expect people to use colons and semicolons correctly: it’s part of literacy, part of standard written English.

Comment: @Mazura Also, mixing *can* and *was* sounds off, some sort of tense mismatch in your conditionals.  These combinations work much better: (1) You **can** use “them” if there **is** a semicolon. (2) You **could** use “them” if there **were** a semicolon. (3) You **could have** used “them” if there **had been** a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence can be recast with both "them" and the comma still utilized:

*There are (more than) 300 million English speakers (in) India, most of (them) **having** acquired English (as) a second language.*

Surely, I do not pretend this would have been a choice available in the real test, still I think it makes an useful point in terms of alternative phrasing.

Comment: That’s a (perfect) gerund clause, which is not tensed. Infinitive clauses also work in that slot for the same reason. It’s easier with a perfect infinitive than a simple one: “There will be more than 500 million English speakers in India by 2030, most **to have acquired** English as a second language.”

Comment: @tchrist That infinitive sentence sounds ungrammatical to me.